# C error Array: array type has incomplete element type.

Tags: c, arrays

I have:

```
extern int docx(char *,char[][]) // in a header file
```

It is compiled properly in solaris, but in Redhat Linux it shows the error bellow:

```
array type has incomplete element type.
```

I know i can solve it as - `char[][20]`

Is it the right way?

Answer (score 17):

You will have to know what the function is actually expecting and modify the interface accordingly. If it is expecting a bidimensional array (`char [N][M]`) the correct interface would be:

```
extern int docx(char *,char*[M]);
```

Which is different from:

```
extern int docx( char*, char** );
```

In the first case the function would be expecting a pointer into a contiguous block of memory that holds `N*M` characters (`&p[0][0]+M == &p[1][0]` and `(void*)&p[0][0]==(void*)&p[0]`), while in the second case it will be expecting a pointer into a block of memory that holds `N` pointers to blocks of memory that may or not be contiguous (`&p[0][0]` and `&p[1][0]` are unrelated and `p[0]==&p[0][0]`)

```
// case 1
ptr ------> [0123456789...M][0123.........M]...[0123.........M]

// case 2
ptr ------> 0 [ptr] -------> "abcde"
            1 [ptr] -------> "another string"
              ...
            N [ptr] -------> "last string"
```

Answer (score 2):

`char *[M]`
is no different from `char **`. `char *[M]` is an array of pointers to char. The dimension plays no role in C (in this case). What David meant was `char (*)[M]` which is a pointer to an array of M chars which would be the correct type for your prototype - but your `char [][M]` is fine also (in fact it is the more common formulation).